# How to use bluetooth dongle instead of internal chip?

Tags: usb, kernel, bluetooth, macbook-pro

I'm trying to disable my internal bluetooth and use a dongle instead, so I found another question on here that said I should run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/config.d/config
```

and add

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0cf3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3004", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

I just installed Ubuntu on my mac so I don't know much about Ubuntu. Was this the correct command to run? It doesn't seem like it did anything, my internal bluetooth is still running...

Comment: The command is probably correct (can't confirm) but in any case VID&PID should match the ones for your specific hardware. `lsusb` should give you the correct values (the hardware in your example would show up as "0cf3:3004", replace with the ones for your own dongle). And better use `sudo -H gedit ... ` instead of the old `gksudo`.

Comment: The dongle is now set as default, but both of them are running...my mac becomes discoverable when I search for devices :s

Comment: Try creating the file as /etc/udev/rules.d/80-bluetooth.rules     Then reboot