How to configure Ubuntu 24.04.01 to use an external USB Bluetooth adapter?
I bought an external USB Bluetooth adapter because I am having problems with my Bluetooth connection.
When I plug the adapter into a USB port nothing changes (it still uses the default hardware).
How should I configure Ubuntu to detect and use the USB Bluetooth adapter?

Ubuntu 24.04.01
Lenovo IdeaPad L340
Ugreen CM748 Bluetooth adapter


Take a look at the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/978586/how-to-use-bluetooth-dongle-instead-of-internal-chip I think the comments suggest the string (updated with you idvender & idproduct details)  in the question is placed in a new file @ /etc/udev/rules.d/80-bluetooth.rules (idvender & idproduct are got from running 'sudo lsusb'
